# Parsing an XML document from the internet

Tags: xml

I'm new to XML Parsing. I am trying to access the "I Heart Quotes" API. This is the piece of code generating the error:

```
String link = "http://www.iheartquotes.com/api/v1/random.xml";
URL url = new URL(link);
InputStream is = url.openStream();
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(is);`
```

And this is the error:

```
Content is not allowed in prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed       in prolog.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:256)           at   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:345)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
at com.nicolasekhoury.IHQuotes.IHQuotes.main(IHQuotes.java:28)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Have you made any progress on this? Think of adding more detail if not or accepting an answer if it solved your question.

Answer (score 1):

When I open http://www.iheartquotes.com/api/v1/random.xml in my browser, the are escaped symbols and I think it is not xml at all - it is just a freeform text.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the [mentioned resource](http://www.iheartquotes.com/api/v1/random.xml) gives an output similar to this:

```
You are fairminded, just and loving.

[fortune] http://iheartquotes.com/fortune/show/46886
```

This is not XML, since it is not [well-formed](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-well-formed).

What I think you should do depends. If this is just for learning go find a real XML source (e.g. [your Stack Overflow user feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/user/2865564)) and fiddle around with it. If you need to work with exactly this data source then look for something else than XML.

I just found that they offer HTML which is not XML but can work with an XML parser under certain circumstances. Read [their docs](http://www.iheartquotes.com/api) and try accessing `http://www.iheartquotes.com/api/v1/random?format=html` which will give you output similar to this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>I Heart Quotes - Random Quote Widget</title>
<style type="text/css">/* ... */</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="rbroundbox">
    <div class="rbtop"><div></div></div>
            <div class="rbcontent">
<a target="_parent" 
   href='http://www.iheartquotes.com/fortune/show/halleys_comet_it_came_we_saw_we_drank'>
Halley's Comet: It came, we saw, we drank.
</a>
<div class="source">
<a target="_parent" 
   href="http://www.iheartquotes.com/fortune/rand?source=codehappy">[codehappy quote]</a>
</div>
</div><!-- /rbcontent -->
    <div class="rbbot"><div></div></div>
    </div><!-- /rbroundbox -->
</td></tr></table>
</body>
</html>
```